# How to create a shared server by SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I am a newbie and I have a question.

How to create a SQL server. It can only be shared with the person who uses the same internet IP address. I spent 2 days but can't do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Given that one SQL Server instance can be used by tens of thousands of users out of the box ... what is the question? You shouldn't have to spend more time than you need to run Setup, which is a few minutes.

Comment: Simply connect to SQL Server via typing Server IP as next: - https://i.stack.imgur.com/tj827.png

Comment: yes, but from another computer.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos, i just need share my server with ten person. how way?

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand correctly, your SQL Server instance is on your computer, and you want other people to be able to connect to it?

The first thing you need to do is enable remote connections : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms191464.aspx

You may also need to enable TCP connections and configure your instance to listen on a particular TCP port : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms177440.aspx

You may also need to configure your firewall to allow connections via the relevant port(s).

Other users can then connect using your machine name/IP and instance name/port number.

Comment: UberDoodles, thanks for your answer, can you add my skype: vu.ndk38@gmail.com, i want to become a data development as you. but it very hard to me with a lot of information on Internet and i don't know where to begin.

Comment: @VũNgô what you asked here is covered in every tutorial. There are dozens of duplicate questions already in SO that ask how to allow remote connections. You *really* should read the docs. It takes less time than typing an SO question

Comment: @VũNgô check for example the [list of tutorials in the SQL Server documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231699.aspx)., especially [Tutorial: Getting Started with the Database Engine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345318.aspx). The first lesson is about connecting from the local machine. The second about remote connections

Comment: Thanks all for help :)